Calculating the cross-sectional area of a river with a large amount of coordinate data inputted using a txt file
So I want to calculate the cross-sectional area of a river with an irregular channel, and also I want to calculate the cross-sectional area for every 1 metre rise in water level to the highest elevation of the cross-section. I encountered a problem that the program I created could not loop to the next cross section, and hopefully I can interpolate correctly to calculate the cross-sectional area for every 1 metre rise in water level in the channel. The next problem is that I want to know how my code can detect when interpolating the depth (y) value between two variables of coordinate data and can be re-entered sequentially into one cross-section coordinate matrix. I hope the problem I expressed is clear enough and anyone can help me. The programming language I am using is Fortran 90. Thank you.
program Read_Cross

implicit none
integer, parameter :: dp = selected_real_kind(15,307)
real(kind=dp), allocatable :: x(:), y(:), z(:), Y_New(:), X_New(:) 
real(kind=dp) :: area1, area0, area, min_Y, max_Y, y_diff, X_int
integer :: i, n_Titik, iostat, n_Penampang, Y_Step, Y_Start
character(len=20) :: Header_Penampang

open(unit = 10, file = 'penampang_multi.txt', status = 'old', action = 'read')
n_Penampang = 0

do 
    ! Read Header Setiap Data Penampang
    read(10, '(A)', iostat=iostat) Header_Penampang
    if (iostat /= 0) exit  ! Akhiri jika sudah sampai akhir file

    n_Penampang = n_Penampang + 1 ! Menghitung jumlah penampang
    
    ! Read jumlah titik koordinat setiap penampang
    read(10, *, iostat=iostat) n_Titik
    if (iostat /= 0) exit ! Akhiri jika sudah mencapai akhir

    ! Alokasikan array sesuai jumlah titik
    allocate(x(n_Titik), y(n_Titik), z(n_Titik))

    ! Baca titik koordinat dari file
    do i = 1, n_Titik
        read(10, *) x(i), y(i), z(i)
    end do

    ! Mulai hitung luas penampang sebagai poligon
    area1 = 0.0_dp
    do i = 1, n_Titik - 1
        area1 = area1 + (x(i) * y(i + 1) - y(i) * x(i + 1))
    end do
    ! Menghubungkan titik terakhir dengan titik pertama
    area1 = area1 + (x(n_Titik) * y(1) - y(n_Titik) * x(1))
    area = abs(area1) / 2.0_dp

    ! Cari nilai minimum dan maksimum dari Y
    min_Y = minval(y)
    max_Y = maxval(y)

    ! Alokasikan array Y_New untuk interpolasi
    allocate(Y_New(n_Titik))
    allocate(X_New(n_Titik))
    
    Y_Step= int(max_Y-min_Y)
    
    ! Melakukan interpolasi nilai Y baru
    Y_Start = min_Y
    do i=2, Y_Step
        Y_New(1) = Y_Start+1
        Y_New(i) = Y_New(i-1) + 1.0_dp  ! Kenaikan Y sebesar 1 meter
            if (Y_New(i) > max_Y) then      ! Keluar dari loop jika Y_New melebihi Y maksimum
            end if
    end do

    ! Interpolasi nilai X baru berdasarkan Y baru
    do i = 1, Y_Step
        if ((Y_New(i) > y(i)).and.(Y_New(i) < y(i+1))) then
            X_New(i) = x(i) + (x(i+1) - x(i)) * (Y_New(i) - y(i)) / (y(i+1) - y(i))
        end if
    end do

    ! Print hasil koordinat dan luas penampang
    print *, "Penampang", n_Penampang
    do i = 1, n_Titik
        print *, "Koordinat (x, y, z): ", x(i), y(i), z(i)
    end do
    do i=1, Y_Step
    print *, "Hasil Interpolasi Kedalaman", Y_New(i), "m :", X_New(i), Y_New(i)
    end do
    print *, "Luas Penampang: ", area

    ! Deallocate array setelah selesai
    deallocate(x, y, z, Y_New, X_New)

end do

close(10)

end program Read_Cross

This is the format file of channel coordinates that have to input into the program using txt file
Penampang1

7 (Jumlah Titik)

0 10 0

0 1 0

2 1 0

3 1 0

4 1 0

4 10 0

0 10 0

Penampang2

4 (Jumlah Titik)

0 8 5

2 3 5

4 8 5

0 8 5

Penampang3

7 (Jumlah Titik)

0 12 6

2 8 6

4 8 6

5 8 6

6 8 6

8 12 6

0 12 6

Penampang4

6 (Jumlah Titik)

0 12 7

2 10 7

4 8 7

5 6 7

7 9 7

8 10 7

Penampang5

6 (Jumlah Titik)

0 12 8

2 10 8

4 8 8

5 6 8

7 9 8

8 10 8

Penampang6

6 (Jumlah Titik)

0 12 9

2 10 9

4 8 9

5 6 9

7 9 9

8 10 9

Penampang7

6 (Jumlah Titik)

0 12 10

2 10 10

4 8 10

5 6 10

7 9 10

8 10 10

My expectation is that the program can interpolate the coordinates needed to calculate the cross-sectional area of the channel at every 1 metre rise in water level and can be done with a large number and variety of cross-sections such as the case of rivers.

It might be just me, @Fiqih Rahmanto, but I'm having a hard time understanding exactly what you want here. Perhaps you can have another go at describing both what you want to do and what your code is doing wrong at the moment. I would also suggest that you start with a SINGLE river cross-section, and ask how the cross-sectional area will change with water depth relative to the invert. This is the sort of job that an individual subroutine would do. You are making it unnecessarily confusing by having multiple stations, because it's difficult to understand what form your output should take.
